# Cannot display Arabic characters in reports 12c runtime?

Tags: oracle, report, arabic

When running report builder , it display arabic fonts very well.
But when calling from Forms 12c runtime , it's appeared in strange  characters not question marks? like the image below:

ÊÞÑíÑ ãßÊÈ ÇáÚãá

I tried to  choose Arial font  but not fixed.

Comment: Maybe this one: [defaultcharset](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/formsandreports/deploy-forms/configure.htm#sthref160)

Comment: Thanks for reply , but I where to change the value of DEFAULTCHARSET